# Mobile events like tap, swipe with emberjs

Tags: jquery, mobile, ember.js

Is there any prior art/literature around how to deal with **touch events on mobile in an emberjs app**?

The most common one is a `tap` event but I cant find anything which discusses it in the context of an emberjs application.

Can using jquery just work? There is jquery mobile as well but I am concerned integrating that with ember might open a different can of worms.

Ember has support for touchEvents but then one still has to do work to simulate a `tap`, `swipe` or `pinch` event for instance.

Thoughts? How are people doing mobile apps using Emberjs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check out [ember-hammertime](https://github.com/html-next/ember-hammertime) and [ember-gestures](https://github.com/html-next/ember-gestures) as examples of some community approaches. Also [look for 'touch' on ember-observer](https://emberobserver.com/?query=touch)

You have to think of everything as touch now, it's not really a *mobile* app issue anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Just use closure actions. Generally I would not rely on jQuery events.
However I don't think `tap` is a real event. 
Well, most devices trigger `onclick` when you tap. But you can attach any event:

```
<div ontouchstart={{action 'foo'}}>foo</foo>
```

If you want to do more complex things consider to build a component for it.

Comment: Haven't tried yet but its well known/documented that there is a 300ms delay between user `tap` and a click event firing. So triggering `onclick` might not be efficient. Also, there are other gestures like `swipe` etc to think about.

Comment: Have you considered the [addons](https://github.com/html-next/ember-gestures) that are available? Of course you can just do plain jQuery, but I wouldn't recommend that.